# aplicar efecto a una imagen con css?

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo el siguiente enlace con una icono al lado izquierdo. Quiero agregarle el efecto de que cuando se de al enlace solo vibre la imagen con la clase vibrar. Asi como lo tengo solo se aplica el efecto cuando le doy click encima de la imagen.

```
.vibrar:active{
  -webkit-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
  -moz-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
  -o-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
 -ms-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes tiembla{
  0%  { -webkit-transform:rotateZ(-5deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform:rotateZ( 0deg) scale(1.4); }
  100%{ -webkit-transform:rotateZ( 5deg); }
```

}

```
<li><a class="opcionmenu" id="verclientes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalverclientes"> <img class="vibrar" src="~/Content/img/Ojo.png" /> Ver Clientes</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El error esta en la definición de la clase. Estas indicando que la animación se realice sobre el elemento con clase `.vibrar` este `:active`. Es decir, cuando el tag `img` este activo.

Solución:

Asignar la clase `.vibrar` al tag `a` e indicar que la animación se realice cuando este elemento este `:active`, se anime el elemento con clase, por ejemplo `.icono`.

```css
.icono {
  height: 15px;
}
.vibrar:active .icono {
  -webkit-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
  -moz-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
  -o-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
 -ms-animation: tiembla 0.2s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes tiembla {
  0%  { -webkit-transform:rotateZ(-5deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform:rotateZ( 0deg) scale(1.4); }
  100%{ -webkit-transform:rotateZ( 5deg);
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="opcionmenu vibrar" id="verclientes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalverclientes">
    <img class="icono" src="http://us.cdn3.123rf.com/168nwm/darrenwhi/darrenwhi0803/darrenwhi080300023/2694785-ilustracion-de-dibujos-animados-en-blanco-y-negro-ojos.jpg" />
    Ver Clientes
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es reemplazar 'active' por la pseudo clase ':hover' y aplicar la clase 'vibrar' al enlace (el elemento `<a>`). Esto hará vibrar todo (imagen y enlace). En caso que al pasar sobre el enlace, vibre la imagen, hay que modificar mucho más.